# Provability of a Godel sentence

Tags: logic

I have been going through Godel 's incompleteness results recently and there is something I fail to understand about the provability of Godel 's sentence G(T) in the theory T:

In T it is provable that con(T) implies G(T), but it is also trivially true that non con(T) implies G(T), as if T is inconsistent then everything can be proven. Thus we can prove in T that (con(T) or non con(T)) implies G(T) and thus G(T) is a tautology in T and G(T) is proven in T.

I fail to see where is the mistake in the above argument and I have been thinking about it for quite some time, obviously there must be something I didn't understand about the underlying definition of provability.

Comment: See [Gödel's second incompleteness theorem](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#SecIncThe) : "Assume $T$ is a **consistent** formalized system which contains elementary arithmetic. Then $T ⊬ Cons(T)$." The poof is : $T ⊢ Cons(T) → G(T)$; thus, **if** $T ⊢ Cons(T)$, then by *modus ponens* $T ⊢ G(T)$, contradicting First Th. So, we have to reject the assumption that $T ⊢ Cons(T)$ and conclude with : $T ⊬ Cons(T)$. All this under the *assumption* that $T$ **is** consistent.

Comment: If $T$ is consistent, it **cannot** prove $G(T)$. If $T$ is **in**consistent, it prove everything, $G(T)$ included. Of course, either $T$ is cons or $T$ is **in**cons, but nothing follows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trivially true that $\neg\mathrm{Con}(T)$ proves $G(T)$; certainly a contradiction would trivially prove it, but $\neg\mathrm{Con}(T)$ is only a contradiction if we *also* know $\mathrm{Con}(T)$, which $T$ does not. So $T$ only proves $(\mathrm{Con}(T) \vee (\mathrm{Con}(T) \wedge \neg\mathrm{Con}(T))) \implies G(T)$ - which is just equivalent to $\mathrm{Con}(T) \implies G(T)$.

It's worth noting that just because $\neg\mathrm{Con}(T)$ is true in a model of $T$ doesn't mean $T$ is actually consistent - it just means there's something the model *thinks* is a proof of a contradiction. The model is allowed to be wrong; indeed, if $T$ is actually consistent, the model *will* be wrong.

EDIT: To respond to your comment below: $T$ can be wrong about what a proof *is*. For example, for us a "proof" is a finite sequence of steps obeying certain specific rules of deduction and invoking only the members of $T$; for Godel's purposes, we encode this as a number. But the thing is, if we have a *nonstandard* model of $T$ (a model of $T$ that isn't the usual model of $PA$) we might have an infinite element which $T$ thinks is a proof. There's no way to say "finite" in $T$. This gives us a "proof" which has infinitely many steps - which means that even if each step follows from the one before, there's going to be a "disconnect". That is, you can't get from the beginning to the end with an unbroken chain of reasoning. That means that the "conclusion" can just say whatever it likes.

So in other words, a model of $T$ might think there's a proof of $0=1$. If it thinks that, it's because it has something it *thinks* is a proof, but really isn't (assuming $T$ is "actually" consistent). This model also thinks, therefore, that proven things aren't necessarily true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Reese, in Godel 's argument con(T) reads " there is no proof of 0=1". I fail to see how non con(T) cannot be a contradiction here ? (I should have mentioned I am looking at PA)

Comment: @OscarElbaz I've edited my answer with an elaboration about this - my response was too long for a comment.

Comment: I see thank you for your answer, this answers my question, I was assuming that non con(T) leads necessary to a contradiction which would be true if T proves con(T).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $T$ actually is consistent, it is not true that $T + \neg \mathrm{Con}(T) \vdash \phi$ for any sentence $\phi$ (and in particular, for $G(T)$). This is because although $\neg \mathrm{Con}(T)$ claims that there is a proof of $\phi$ from $T$, you cannot extract this proof "internally in the logic" using only $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument seems to hinge on the reasoning

> If $T$ is inconsistent then it proves everything, so in that case $G_T$ is provable and therefore true.

But just because $T$ *proves* $G_T$ doesn't mean that $G_T$ is necessarily *true* in the intended interpretation. It might be that $T$ proves some falsehoods, and that will indeed be the case whenever $T$ is inconsistent.

Comment: Yes you are right I misformulated myself when I said "if T is inconsistent then everything can be proven to be true": I meant "if T is inconsistent then every proposition can be proven". My point was to show (obviously I am wrong somewhere) that T proves G(T) by saying T proves con(T) implies G(T) and T proves non con(T) implies G(T). I will edit my initial post.

Comment: @OscarElbaz: And your mistake is exactly that $T$ _does not_ prove $\neg\operatorname{Con}(T)\to G_T$.

Comment: Indeed I got my mistake, indeed non con(T) is not a contradiction in T otherwise T would prouve con(T). Thank you guys !